# Using lapply to generate multiple graphs, iterate over the list to title the graphs not working

Tags: r, loops, split, lapply

I created the following code to successfully generate graphs I wanted from the list "hemi_split", however the following error is generated when I try to title the graphs

`"Error in hemi_split[i] : invalid subscript type 'list' "

Here is the code

```
graphs <- lapply(hemi_split, function(i){ 
  ggplot(data=i, aes(x=type, y=shoot.mass))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(.~host)+ 
    theme_minimal()+
    labs(title=names(hemi_split[i]))
         })
```

And here are the names of the list elements that I want to title each graph

```
names(hemi_split)
 [1] "CADE" "CAFO" "CAHI" "CALE" "CAMI" "CARU" "CAWI" "COPI" "REEL" "TRER" "TRVE"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Using `purrr`'s `imap`, you can access data as well as name.

```
graphs <- purrr::imap(hemi_split, ~{ 
             ggplot(data=.x, aes(x=type, y=shoot.mass))+
             geom_point()+
             facet_wrap(.~host)+ 
             theme_minimal()+
             labs(title=.y)
           })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do lapply on the list, you lose track of the names, you can try:

```
graphs <- lapply(names(hemi_split), function(i){ 
  ggplot(data=hemi_split[[i]], aes(x=type, y=shoot.mass))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(.~host)+ 
    theme_minimal()+
    labs(title=i))
         })
```